# How to install libSM in a virtual env on Mac

Tags: macos, opencv, pipenv

I am having difficulty with OpenCV in a virtual environment (namely pipenv) as I am receiving the error

```
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have found many solutions suggesting installing libsm6 via apt-get or yum, however these do not exist on mac and I cannot find any installation guides online.

**How do I install libsm6 in a virtual environment on macOS?**

I'd even accept installing it locally to then be copied over into the virtual environment's packages.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you yesterday.

You can solve the problem as follows:

- 1 copy the libSM.so.6 to a Folder (e.g. `/data00/chenpengda/lib_files`)
- 2 vim the .bashrc，add line:

  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data00/chenpengda/lib_files
- 3 source the .bashrc